# Google drive broken links for ajax for Chrome and Safari

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, http-headers, google-drive-api

I have the next issue. I have a public folder in google drive. There link: 
googledrive.com/host/0BwY6DLBm4YpZT0NaWF9zT0dBMVU/. If I go to this link 6c393817e37aef22a43cf36bfb94a77d56fd1f77.googledrive.com/host/0BwY6DLBm4YpZT0NaWF9zT0dBMVU/ . And all links broken on my site, because I using googledrive.com/host/0BwY6DLBm4YpZT0NaWF9zT0dBMVU/. How to resolve this issue? I think some issues with headers in http response on backend. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like Google has added an Id prefix to any hosted page in Google Drive, and the "301 Moved Permanently" conversion is broken < all started this morning

the 301 translation wipes out the parameters and does not respect the s in the https calls

Please, star this issue to get more attention from their support team

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4084

Comment: it looks like this issue is fixed, at list for now

Comment: it's back again, not funny